# Midnight Commander hotkey for selectbox or field with [ ^ ]

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, mc

For example **mc** FTP dialog field have this symbol:

[image: Midnight Commander FTP connection]

It looks like selectbox. I think this is can be history.

How to activate/open it with keyboard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The history shortcut is <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>.

It appears in some views you need to replace the lowercase `h` with an uppercase `H` for the history (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd>).

Comment: For keybindings, look into `~/.config/mc/mc.keymap` or, if you do not have one, `/usr/local/etc/mc/mc.default.keymap`.

Comment: Thanks! `Esc`+`h` working perfect in MacOS iTerm2 MC 4.8.11